# Checking additional static properties on lazy singleton pattern (Jon Skeet singleton)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, thread-safety, singleton, lazy-loading

I'm implementing [Jon Skeet's Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) using `System.Lazy<T>`.

My singleton differs slightly though.  My singleton class represents the configuration of one of my services, and that service has a connection to a database.  I have an additional readonly static property that returns `true` if my service is disconnected.

I did this by checking the `IsValueCreated` property on the lazy object first, and calling `Value` if it has not been created to ensure that when I check my `ConnectionString` property, my singleton has been instantiated.

Is there a more elegant way of implementing `Disconnected`?  Is disconnected thread safe in this current implementation (without `lock`s)? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Example code below:

```
    public sealed class MyServiceConfiguration {
        private static Lazy<MyServiceConfiguration> lazy = new Lazy<MyServiceConfiguration>(() => new MyServiceConfiguration());

        private static string ConnectionString = "";

        public static MyServiceConfiguration Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

        public static bool Disconnected {
            get {
                if (!lazy.IsValueCreated) { lazy.Value; }
                return ConnectionString == "";
            }
        }

        private MyServiceConfiguration() {
            //...additional service configuration options...
            ConnectionString = "someConnectionString";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain at the interface level what you want to achieve? Without implementation details.

Comment: There is no interface, as this is a singleton pattern.  At the top level, anywhere in the code I should be able to check if `MyServiceConfiguration.Disconnected`.

Comment: Interface is the set of public methods and properties your class provides. Therefore every class has an interface. Currently it's not clear what Disconnected is supposed to do, how the ConnectionString must be used. All your methods are static, but you have a private constructor. Therefore, for the beginning, you need to define in human language the semantics of the class. "I want to be able to..."

Comment: I don't see how this isn't clear - I just told you I need to be able to check if `MyServiceConfiguration.Disconnected` returns true or false.  The implementation then clearly shows that this returns `true` if `ConnectionString == ""`.  Am I missing something?